# How can I prove that for modular multiplicative inverses that if $∃ $[$b$]$ ∈ℤ_n$ such that [$a$] * [$b$] = [$1$], then gcd($a,n$) =$1$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

How can I prove that for modular multiplicative inverses that if $∃ $[$b$]$ ∈ℤ_n$ such that [$a$] * [$b$] = [$1$], then gcd($a,n$) =$1$?

I understand the relationship between primes and multiplicative inverses, but I am not sure how to prove that

if $∃ $[$b$]$ ∈ℤ_n$ such that [$a$] * [$b$] = [$1$], $⇒ $ gcd($a,n$) =$1$

I have some definitions to work with, but I am not sure how to fully write out the proof.

gcd($m,n$) is defined as the smallest element of the set $S$ = {$K∈N$ : $k=mx+ny$ for some $x,y∈ℤ$}.

I know that gcd($m,n$) = $1$ when they are primes.

Multiplicative Inverse for modulo is defined as [$b$]$∈ℤ_n$ if [$a$] * [$b$] = [$1$].

I can prove the converse better, but I am not quite sure how to start with $∃ $[$b$]$ ∈ℤ_n$ such that [$a$] * [$b$] = [$1$] to derive gcd($a,n$) = $1$.

I have looked at other posts, but they haven't really shown me what I am looking for. Any help and proofs would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If $a\cdot b\equiv 1\mod n$, you have for some $k$
$$ab=1+kn\iff ab-kn=1,$$
which is a Bézout's relation between $a$ (or $b$) and $n$.

Comment: How can I prove Bézout's relation though? It is not a given by the definitions I have for gcd.

Comment: You never saw that such a Bézout's relation is a criterion for two integers to be coprime??

Comment: I know about Bézout's relation, but it is not something I can directly cite in my proof. I can use Euclid's Lemma and Fermat's Little Theorem though.

Comment: Needless, all the more so as you don't have prime numbers here. Note it is obvious: if a number is a common divisor of $a$ and $n$, it divides as well $ab-kn$, i.e. it divides $1$. The divisors of $1$ are not that many…